# Binary Formatter serialize-deserialize

Tags: c#, memorystream, binaryformatter

I have 2 voids to serialize/Deserialize my class data (what is serializable)

But sometimes i get error:
**TableDataObject translater: The input stream is not a valid binary format. The starting contents (in bytes) are: 21-31-83-C6-7A-60-03-F8-52-B7-87-2C-5A-DE-38-A5-8F ...**

2 voids:

```
public static byte[] GetBytes(TableData obj)
    {
        try
        {
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                bf.Serialize(ms, obj);
                ms.Close();
                return ms.ToArray();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.Log("Byte maker: "+ ex.Message);
            return null;
        }
        
    }
    public static TableData GetObject(byte[] arrBytes)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                var binForm = new BinaryFormatter();
                memStream.Write(arrBytes, 0, arrBytes.Length);
                memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                TableData obj = (TableData)binForm.Deserialize(memStream);
                return obj;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.Log("TableDataObject translater: "+ ex.Message);
            return null;
        }
        
    }
```

I m expecting 0 error because it s an easy task

Comment: Do not use `BinaryFormatter`. Ever. [Warning in Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter?view=net-7.0#remarks) + [Deserialization risks in use of BinaryFormatter and related types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/binaryformatter-security-guide)

Comment: Did you serialize the data with the same version of Net/Core that you are using to deserialize?  Remove ms.Close(); which is not needed in a using block.  You may not be flushing the ms.

Comment: Please do not use `BinaryFormatter`, it is slow, inefficient, fragile, insecure, and kills puppies.  Use a modern serialization method. If you want a binary format I would recommend protobuf .net, it is better than BinaryFormatter in just about any metric.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the same .net version, the only problem can be I'm sending from a Standalone Windows build the datas into an Universal Windows Plarform build